# Excel : Match Function is Unknown (Not Even Found in Function Library)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-match

My problem is that the function `MATCH` is not recognized in Excel (I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010).

The Error:

[image: The Error]

When I try to evaluate the formula, I get this (this proves that the `MATCH` function is not recognized):

[image: This prove that "MATCH" function is not recognized]

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Your **language settings** may require a different spelling for ***Match***

Comment: Yes, STUPID ME :D

Comment: From your #NOM? I would assume "EQUIV"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `EQUIV` in case you're using a French version of Excel.

[Here](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-french.html) you can find translation for every function in 14 languages.